# Laravel Sanctum with SPA doesn't handle logout correctly. I doesn't seem to maintain the logout status. What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, session, single-page-application

So my website (Laravel with React) doesn't seem to work the way I want. I use Laravel Sanctum for (SPA, so cookie, not token) authentication. And if I use the normal logout, it seems to logout, but after a refresh, I'm still authenticated. I created my own logout controller to check but the weird thing is, it seems to logout... but after a refresh I'm not. The controller with the stuff I've tried:

```
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            dump('Logged out!');
        }

        $sessionId = $request->session()->getId();

        if($request->session()->invalidate()){
            dump('Session invalidated!');
        }

        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->remove($sessionId);
        session_unset();
        Session::flush();
        Session::forget($sessionId);

        $cookie = Cookie::forget($sessionId);
```

I know all of this is overkill, but it's just to show what I've tried (stuff I found online with answers to similar problems). The weird thing is, the dump spits out that I'm logged out and the session is invalidated... but when I do an Axios call (or after a refresh) to check, I'm still logged in. I check with an Axios call that spits out `Auth::user();`

I tried just deleting the session cookie with forget, but that also does nothing with the cookies. It looks like the session isn't invalidated (I think), but the dump says it is. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] So I tried some other stuff... apparently the redirect plays a part in this! The Laravel redirect wasn't triggered because I used a React redirect on the frontend logout method. Removing the frontend redirect triggered the backend Laravel redirect... and then after refreshing I was indeed logged out! Yay. Also, dumping info (using dump() in php) prevents a successful logout!